# how to sort out values in categories from lists in order to access data from variables in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, if-statement

I have a python scraping script to get infos about some upcomming concerts and it's the same text pattern everytime no matter how many concerts will appear, the only difference is that sometimes it will show an additional line with the price of the tickets when they are still available to book such as the example below:

```
LIVE 01/01/99 9PM
Iron Maiden
Madison Square Garden 
New York City
LIVE 01/01/99 9.30PM
The Doors
Staples Center
Los Angeles
LIVE 01/02/99 8.45PM
Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg
Staples Center
Los Angeles
Book a ticket now for $99,99
LIVE 01/02/99 9PM
Diana Ross
City Hall
New York City 
Book a ticket now for $79,99       ect...
```

I need to sort these blocks between 2 categories (4 lines blocks & 5 lines blocks) and then iterate through the values in my variables (bands, date, location, price ect...)

It's working perfectly fine if I have either 4 lines block only or 5 lines block only, but when I have both kind of blocks like in my sample text I don't know how to put them into their own categories, I've tried many formulations in my if statement but none of them worked

```
live_lines = []
line_counter = 0
distances = []
with open('concerts_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    reading_file = file.read()
    lines = reading_file.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('LIVE'):
            live_lines.append(line_counter)

        line_counter += 1

for position in range(len(live_lines)-1):
    block_lines = live_lines[position+1] - live_lines[position]
    block_sizes.append(block_lines)

print('live_lines:', live_lines) #output = [0,4,8,13]
print('block_sizes', block_sizes) #output = [4,4,5]

if block_sizes == 4 for block_lines in live_lines:
    dates = [i for i in lines [0::4]] #output desired = ["LIVE 01/01/99 9PM", "LIVE 01/01/99 9.30PM", "LIVE 01/02/99 8.45PM"]
if block_sizes == 5 for block_lines in live_lines:
    dates = [i for i in lines [0::5]] #output desired = ["LIVE 01/02/99 9PM"]
```

This `dates` variable line of code works perfectly fine without an if statement when there are ONLY 4 lines blocks but gets messed up and read 1 char less when a 5 line block appears

```
if block_sizes == 4 for block_lines in live_lines:
    dates = [i for i in lines [0::4]]
```

This `dates` variable line of code works perfectly fine without an if statement when there are ONLY 5 lines blocks but gets messed up and read 1 char more when a 4 line block appears

```
elif block_sizes == 4 for block_lines in live_lines:
    dates = [i for i in lines [0::5]]
```

Comment: where is `if block_sizes == 4` in relation to the full code?

Comment: just after both print lines, I edited my code to include it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using regex to parse this text. For example, this regex string will group all lines into separate groups:

```
((LIVE.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(Book.*)|(LIVE.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*))
```

For example, if the variable text contains your sample text:

```
import re

with open("concerts_list.txt", "r") as r:
    text = r.read()

    pattern = r"((LIVE.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(Book.*)|(LIVE.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*))"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)
    matches = [[line for line in match if line] for match in matches] # filter empty groups

    for match in matches:
        if len(match) == 5: #no price data
            print(match[1])
        else:   # price data
            print(match[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep the order, the logic is to iterate between each block in the text file, see how many lines it contains (4 or 5), sort the block between the 2 categories (4 or 5 lines blocks) and then access the data in my variables according to which catergory the block belongs to

Comment: Is that not possible with the code I have edited into my comment?

Comment: I don't know anything in regex, and I've never used pass in my if statements so i'm not familiar, I'd rather keep the same logic and try to get the right formulations for my if statements because everything else is working in my code and I don't wanna mess anything up

Comment: It is really not that hard, just replace `pass` with `print(match[1])` and you will print the dates of all concerts.

Comment: what do you mean by match? and the [1]? and the #no price date with 5 (the price data IS with 5)? So please use the same variables as I use to add more clarity because I do get your regex part but i'm completely lost afterwards thanks

Comment: Please run the code, to see what is happening. `matches` returns a list of tuples, where each tuple is a concert. `match[0]` is the all the lines of the concert, `match[1]` will be the first line of each concert, so the _LIVE data_ part.

Comment: run the code where??? you don't even specify where to put it comparing to my code: just after the with open('concerts_list.txt', 'r') as file: ??I tried to run your code I got an error, for the line: return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, please post full comment and clear explanation with # in your code

Comment: I have updated my code, please comment out your own code and paste this in, this should work on your computer.

Comment: Thanks that's partially working, there's something I don't understand in your logic: considering the first part of the regex with the 'book' is like a 5 lines block right? So why do you put afterwards if len(match) == 5: #no price data, that actually should be the one with price data if it has 5 lines?

Comment: Yeah this if statement does something if the 4 lines + the total group have been found, the one with the price data is actually len(match) == 6.

Comment: that "6" made all difference it's working now, thx a lot!!! i'm gonna try a few more things before putting this as solved, I might have a few more questions if you don't mind?

Comment: by the way, why is it len(match) == 6 while we have a maximum 5 lines block? why 1 above? I just wanna understand and learn ;)

Comment: As said before, it is every line grouped (5) + the whole group (1) that is contained in match.

Comment: thx now I get it, I have another question, how can I access the value inside a certain match, let's say I only want the first date in my dates variable ("LIVE 01/01/99 9PM"), how do I access it? I've tried match[1][0] it doesn't work. And a second question, let's say I only want the hours in my dates variable ("9PM", "9.30PM", "8.45PM", "9PM") how do I access them? thanks

Comment: Yes with `match[1][0]` you will slice the string so you will get `L`. what we can do is to split the string at every space, by `var = match[1].split(" ")`. Here `var[0]` == `LIVE`, `var[1]` == `01/01/99` and `var[2]` == `9PM`. To underand this please look up the split function and indexing arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. What about my first question to only access the 1st date in my dates variables in order to just get ("LIVE 01/01/99 9PM")?

Comment: Just to clarify, I wanna be able to access any date line in my dates variables (so any of these: LIVE 01/01/99 9PM, LIVE 01/01/99 9.30PM, LIVE 01/02/99 8.45PM, LIVE 01/02/99 9PM) so following my previous comment, let's say I wanna get only the 1st date (LIVE 01/01/99 9PM) in my dates, how to do it please?

Comment: nervermind I found it after thinking back from what you said about split function & indexing arrays, and after a few trials and errors: date = match[1].split("\n"), print('date:',date[0]). band would be band = match[2].split(\n) print('bands:', band[0] ect...

Comment: Great! Have fun with your Python journey!

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help I guess I can put it as solved now ;) have a good one as well!